# Error on two dimensional array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

The goal of my program is to load data from a file into the sales array and then display each cities sales for each day before moving onto the next city. I am having problems passing my two dimensional SalesArray to my other functions. I am pretty sure it is because of the way I am declaring it in global and in main. I am also having a problem organizing it so it displays each city and days accordingly.

Any help would be great. Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h> 

using namespace std;

double SalesArray;
void GetSales();
void DisplaySales(double SalesArray[5][4]);


int main(){

   DisplayHeading();
   GetSales();
   DisplaySales(double(SalesArray)[5][4]) ;

   cout << endl;
   system("pause");
   return 0;

}


void GetSales(){

   double SalesArray[5][4]; 
   ifstream indata;
   indata.open("sales.txt");

   for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++){
            indata >> SalesArray[row][col] ;    
        }
   }


   //Close the File
   //indata.close();

   //cout << endl;

}

void DisplaySales(double SalesArray[5][4]){

    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++){
            cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << SalesArray[row][col] << endl;
        }
    }


    // Array for City
    const int SIZE = 5;
    string city[SIZE] = {"New York" , "LA" , 
                 "Chicago" , "Springfield" ,
                 "Prophetstown" };

    for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count ++){
         cout << city[count] << endl;
    }

    // Array for Days

    const int SALES = 4;
    string days[SALES] = {"Friday" , "Saturday" , 
                 "Sunday" , "Monday"
                 };

    for (int count = 0; count < SALES;  count ++){
        cout << days[count] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post whole file. Try to put minimum code snippet that will show your problem. Remember to indent it. In your program you are declaring array incorrectly because you declare one value did you miss '*'? Read about pointers and arrays

Answer (score 1):

Yes, remove the local declaration of `SalesArray` in `GetSales();` even better, make it an argument and pass it in just like `DisplaySales()`.

Also, you should pass in all of `SalesArray`, not the element at `[5][4]`.

```
     DisplaySales( SalesArray );
```

Note... the element at `[5][4]` is beyond the end of the array.  In `C`, you declare the size `N`, but only index to `N-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have multiple declarations of the variable `SalesArray`? So you have a `double SalesArray` in the global, then inside `GetSales()` you have another `double SalesArray[5][4]`. Also in this function, you store the value from the file to this local variable, hence the value is lost after the function finishes.

It's either you use global variable `double SalesArray[5][4]`, or remove your global variable and pass the `SalesArray[5][4]` to the `GetSales` function, so that you can retrieve it later.

Answer (score 0):

The SalesArray you've declared inside `GetSales()` is different to the one in main, once you leave that function it's gone. The simplest fix for that is to change the function prototype to `GetSales(double SalesData[5][4])` and get rid of the function-scoped SalesArray.

Are you looking to display the data in a grid kind of format? If so, you need something like

```
//Display days along top axis
cout << "\t";
for (int count = 0; count < SALES;  count ++){
    cout << days[count] << "\t";
}
cout << endl;

for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++){
    //display city for that row
    cout << city[row] << "\t"; 

    // display each
    for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++){
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << SalesArray[row][col] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

You might have to play about with widths for it to display entirely correctly, but I think that's roughly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The global you are declaring is a single double, not an array. To declare an array it should be something like `double SalesArray[5][4];` In main() you are calling DisplaySales() wrong. Try something like this `DisplaySales(SalesArray);` I agree with the other answers though, you should not declare it as a global and a local or pass the global in as a parameter to another function. Just pick one strategy.